# Handling connection error - try connecting until connected

Tags: r, error-handling, web-scraping, connection, try-catch

In my code, there is a loop, which at each instance connects to a website and takes the source code using `readLines`. Let's use the simplified code, which saves the number of lines in the source code. Also vector `address` contains URLs of websites. We have got:

```
output <- c()
for(i in 1:100){
   website <- readLines(address[i])
   output[i] <- length(website)
}
```

The loop in my code usually runs for several hours and I am facing some internet connection problems from time to time. Therefore, I if there is a problem with connecting to a particular website, I would like to repeat the connection trials until a success is reached.

If I use `tryCatch`, the error would not stop the code's execution, but the data of the particular website would be just ommitted. What I want is to try connecting until connected. Have you got any suggestions how to modify the following code to obtain that?

```
output <- c()
for(i in 1:100){
   tryCatch({
      website <- readLines(address[i])
      output[i] <- length(website)
   })
}
```

Comment: your expression should be in brackets

Comment: I haven't done something like this. What about a `while` loop that will keep running your `tryCatch` until output is created successfully?